How to compile QML live?
I started learning QML, and found a tool like Felgo live, but it requires you to use Felgo, and I have problems installing it, since I compile Qt sources, and I don’t have the maintancetool. Otherwise, the point is not important.
I found a replacement from Qt, namely QML Live https://doc.qt.io/QMLLive/qmllive-index.html
I couldn’t find any binaries anywhere, I need to build them myself. I followed the instructions qmake && make and after make install, but it did not create any binaries, and in principle there was no build.

os: windows 11
I took qmake from the compiled version of qt 6.7.2 in bin
And make I took from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
And the repository from which I took the sources: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-apps-qmllive
downloaded the repository again and tried to build it again

You should copy and paste plain text instead of images when showing compiler output. It shows a message that it cannot find a feature. Does that prevent it from finishing?

I am not sure this is what you want, but, I've been using Qt for WebAssembly which allows you to run Qt snippets, and applications in a web browser https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/wasm.html - If you search online for "qmlonline" you will see quite a few deployments of this. I've used it in some of my StackOverflow answers with a "Try it Online" button.

You can use Visual Studio Code and Extention: QmlSandbox

The extension only works with one file, so we can say that it is useless
